# HyperLink Each Word in a String

Tags: .net, wpf, string, hyperlink, textblock

I have a string, let's say it is `"Hello World"`. I want to display the string in a WPF TextBlock on two different lines. I'd like each word to be associated with a different URL, and want to navigate to the appropriate URL when the user clicks a word.

Is there a way to do this without creating a separate TextBlock for each word?

Comment: Why don't you want to create two text blocks? Is "two" your way of saying "thousands" because you actually have many words to display? If not, I would just create the two text blocks and make it easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want something like:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink>Hello</Hyperlink>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Hyperlink>World</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

It's not at all clear to me why you're trying to avoid two `TextBlock`s or how dynamic your data is, but you could either just code it as above, or look at using an `ItemsControl` that is bound to a list of words and produces a `TextBlock` for each. Afraid there's no easy way to produce a single `TextBlock` from an `ItemsControl` though, as it adds its children to a `Panel`, not an arbitrary element.